# Joining two tables where the join condition requires a substring

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to join two oracle database tables where the columns to join on contain slightly different data.

For example Table A has a column 'ref' and Table B has a column 'id'.

A.ref contains data like A1234567890B and B.id contains data of the form 1234567890

I have tried joining the two based on the following query;

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON SUBSTR(A.ref, 2,10) = B.id;
```

But this has returned no results when I know that there is matching data from this substring.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Query looks good. Try looking at what substr returns. Don't forget that it is 1-based.

Comment: What are the column types? Fixed-length CHAR fields sometimes "misbehave".

Comment: Given your examples (`A1234567890B` and `123456789`) the query [works as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e7c0a/1). What are the data types of each column?

Comment: Works just fine (with two varchar2 columns): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b3be/1

Comment: Works if b.id is int and A.ref is varchar or nvarchar too.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the responses so far. The data types for both columns are CHAR 12 so I'd imagine the value is actually '1234567890  ' on the B side column

Comment: no, the space is at the beginning of the word sometimes. Double check. PS: migrate your datas...

Comment: Either use varchar2 or (if you can't change the datatypes) use trim as in this example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04849/2

Comment: The quickest way to work out what is going wrong is to simply put the joining condition in the select and see why it is not matching(with a X join), for example select SUBSTR(A.ref, 2,10), B.id from a, b and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this in the end by padding out SUBSTR(A.ref, 2,10) to 12 characters.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

`SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON regexp_substr(A.ref, '^[[:alpha:]]+([[:digit:]]+)[[:alpha:]]+$',1,1,'c',1) = B.id`